# regular expression match only one time

Tags: python, regex

I have multi string look like

```
    "Km.Km"
    "Vmax.Km"
    "Kcat.Km"
    "Km"
```

I want to find `Km` only show one time and with only `Km` in the string.
In this case, `Km` are my answer.
I have tried `^(?!.*(Kcat|Vmax)).*Km.*$`, but this will show both `km` like this `Km.Km`, which I need `km` to be only one time.

Comment: Where's the code you are using? That would probably be helpful to include.

Comment: Please clearly show us what must be present in the string and what must be absent.

Comment: Why are `v4.Vmax.div.v4.Km.X8` and `v4.Kcat.mul.v4.Km.X9` excluded? They only have `Km` once each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not very clear what your requirements are for the match, but if you know you want `Km` to appear just once in the middle group you could use

```
In [44]: for item in items:
    ...:     print(re.findall(r'^\w+\.Km\.\w+$', item))
    ...:     
[]
[]
[]
[]
['v4.Km.X9']
['v4.Km.X10']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
re.findall(r'(?i)\b[^.]km\b',string)
Out[40]: [' Km']
```